# How to customize nuxt default html template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js

I try to customize the default page from Nuxt app but the documentation is very poor :

> https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#document

What if i want to get only the title for example ? or only the links in the head ?

```
{{ HEAD.links }}
```

or only the meta ?

```
{{ HEAD.meta }}
```

I don't know the syntax, is this handlebars or something equivalent ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

if you look in the source code, you can found only 4 custom meta:

- HTML_ATTRS
- BODY_ATTRS
- HEAD
- BODY_SCRIPTS

see https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/ef7a42649dcee7e65886b2db1a329deecd93aff2/lib/core/meta.js#L40-L45

---

the HEAD meta is not an object, but an string concat:

```
// Get vue-meta context
const m = await this.getMeta(url)

...

// HEAD tags
meta.HEAD =
  m.meta.text() +
  m.title.text() +
  m.link.text() +
  m.style.text() +
  m.script.text() +
  m.noscript.text()
```

so you cannot get `{{ HEAD.links }}`

---

But, from your `nuxt.config.js` file, you can override all that HEAD data.

eg. if you want only keep the `title`:

replace:

```
head: {
  title: 'starter',
  meta: [
    { charset: 'utf-8' },
    { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
    { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'Nuxt.js project' }
  ],
  link: [
    { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
  ]
}
```

by:

```
head: {
  title: 'starter'
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer ! The problem is that i don't want the title for example. I don't have one in the nuxt.config but nuxt gives me an empty one in the output :(